# How to subset an item:value list using another list with just items?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, word-cloud

I have 2 lists. One is a list of words and their frequencies and the other is a list of words.

```
a = [('country',3478), ('island',2900),('river',5)] 
b = ['river','mountain','bank']
```

There are thousands of entries in a but only hundreds in b.

How can I subset list a so that i return:

```
c=[('river',5)]
```

For loops would take too long given the number of entries and i imagine list comprehension is the solution but cannot get it right.

My main goal is to then create a wordcloud with my final list. Any help would be appreciated

---

**Edited because I made a mistake as pointed out by some commenters. I want to return

```
c=[('river',5)]
```

instead of

```
c=['river',5]
```

as i originally wrote. Apologies and thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You probably want to return it as a *single* tuple?

Comment: List comprehensions will be the same speed as for-loops. If you want faster lookups, you need to use a `dict` instead of a list of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you actually want:

```
c = [('river',5)]  # a list with one tuple
```

You better first construct a set of values in `b`:

```
bd = set(b)
```

then you can use list comprehension:

```
c = [(x,y) for x,y in a if x in bd]
```

That being said, if you want to lookup the frequency of a word, I advice you not to construct a list of tuples, but a dictionary. You can do this with *dictionary comprehension*:

```
c = {x: y for x,y in a if x in bd}  # dictionary variant
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
a = [('country',3478), ('island',2900),('river',5)] 
b = ['river','mountain','bank'] 
final_data = list([i for i in a if i[0] in b][0])
```

Output:

```
['river', 5]
```