# Wordcloud error from dictionary. 'could not convert string to float: 'v'

Tags: python, dictionary, word-cloud

I have a dictionary of words and their respective frequencies that I want to create a wordcloud of. Here is my code.

```
wordcloud= WordCloud(background_color='black', max_words=100,max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate_from_frequencies(c)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

When I run this with 'c' being my dictionary it returns the following error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-a57b2eff5352> in <module>()
  3 #Configure image
  4 #If want to take relative word frequencies into account change to >0.8
----> 5 wordcloud= WordCloud(background_color='black', max_words=100,max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate_from_frequencies(c)
  6 plt.figure()
  7 plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')

C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies)
269         frequencies = frequencies[:self.max_words]
270         # largest entry will be 1
--> 271         max_frequency = float(frequencies[0][1])
272 
273         frequencies = [(word, freq / max_frequency) for word, freq in frequencies]

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'v'
```

I assure you that there is no entry 'v' so I have no clue why it is returning this error. My dictionary is sampled below (there are too many entries to include the full thing)

```
{'able': 2926,
 'account': 9157,
 'afford': 2055,
 'also': 4257,
 'amount': 6746,
 'another': 2027,
 'application': 1950}
```

and I generated my dictionary with the code provided in answer to my last question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794141/how-to-subset-an-itemvalue-list-using-another-list-with-just-items) post.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: it looks like frequencies[0] is a word starting with the letter 'v' and this cannot be converted to a float. Have you tried to print frequencies[0] ?

Comment: @Guillaume.P How would I print frequencies, it's internal to the function and not part of any of my code. If frequencies is my dictionary then there are words beginning with v but why would they be any different to the other strings?

Comment: Ok I didn't realise that was a lib. I had a look at it and it should do what you expect with the dictionary you give. have you tried with an hardcoded dict as follow  c = {'a':1,'b':2} to see what it gives. Do you build the dictionary from a file ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried with a hardcoded dictionary, the exact same one as above but hardcoded rather than built and passed straight in and now the error is 'could not convert string to float: 'p''. The only p in the dictionary is in the middle of the last word. Doesn't make any sense to me. 

As to how I built the library you can see the link in my OP. Thanks again for giving your time to this I appreciate it

Comment: The following code works for me: https://gist.github.com/Ghom/87f3a6d2ded6d2d569c5b62fd440cb8a
does it work for you? if yes try to only put 10 items in your dictionary with the hardcoded version. The dictionary must be the problem. Also try to dump your dictionary in pastbin so we can have a look.

Comment: Hmm. No that didn't work for me it said String index out of range. I guess if that works for you then its not the dicitonary that is the problem?

Comment: Have you had any problem for the install of wordcloud? That might be an install problem. I had a few when I installed it (missing Visual studio 14 and permission denied) and I also had to use the wheel provided on the Readme on git. Maybe try to reinstall and try exemple/simple.py provided in the git repo to confirm everything work correctly.

Comment: Note: I used python 3.6 for my tests